# How to limit specific user ID to 5 comments per post?

Tags: users, comments

Can someone please give me a function to limit a *specific* User ID to 5 comments per post? I found several questions on how to put a limit of one comment per post on all users. However, I need to place the limit on only a single User ID. When I tried to modify the code to specify a single user ID it instead applied the limit to all users based on that one ID.

I found a plugin [Limit Comments and Word Count](https://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-comments-and-word-count/) that includes an option to place a limit on a specific User ID but for some reason that plugin doesn't work on my site. When I place the limit then no comments will go through for that User ID. It just gives a blank screen after hitting the comment button.

Anyway, if someone can give me a simple function to limit the number of comments per post from a *specific* User ID I would very much appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple approach to check whether a user has commented on the post, or not. If they have commented on the post, then disable comment form.

```
global $current_user;
$args = array('user_id' => $current_user->ID);
$usercomment = get_comments($args);
if(count($usercomment) >= 1){
    echo 'Comment form disabled';
} else {
    comment_form();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That would impose the limit on all users correct? Is there a way to modify the code so that the limit only applies to a single user? For instance, if I only want to limit comments for User ID 810 but no other User ID. That is what I need to do.

Comment: @rrhdev... Yes, you can modify the code for the single user.  if you need like that so you check with below codes:

global $current_user;
$get_current_user = $current_user->ID;
if($get_current_user == '810'){
 $args = array('user_id' => $get_current_user);
 $usercomment = get_comments($args);
 if(count($usercomment) >= 1){
     echo 'Comment form disabled';
 } else {
     comment_form();
 }
}

Please check and let us know. Thanks